# Efficient Fall back logic for any Kernel Upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, upgrade, kernel

I am newbie to Ubuntu Linux system. This system has one hard disk with  three disks partition as below

```
fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Device        Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1      2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2   1050624   59643903   58593280    28G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  59643904 1953523711 1893879808 903.1G Linux filesystem
```

There are two kernels are present on two separate disks(sda2, sda3). 
One is active kernel and other one is backup kernel.

Requirement : ***If i upgrade the active kernel with different version of kernel and if it fails, system should boot with the backup kernel and should become active.***. In case if the kernel upgrade is successful, then it should boot with the upgraded kernel rather than backup kernel.

**What would be the efficient rollback(or fall back) mechanism to handle this scenario? Also What and all GRUB related configurations are needed to support this scenario.**

Appreciate if you can throw some light or share any useful logic/Scripts to handle this issue.

Comment: Why would you want to do that, though?

Comment: Trying to maintain latest kernel of every release.

Comment: The system already lets you keep 20 kernels at the cost of 7 GB on a single partition. Not sure why you need more on other partitions...